# Exclude first element of a certain type when doing apply-templates

Tags: xslt

This is my source `XML`:

```
    <DEFINITION>
        <DEFINEDTERM>criminal proceeding</DEFINEDTERM>
        <TEXT> means a prosecution for an offence and includes&#160;&#150;</TEXT>
        <PARAGRAPH>
            <TEXT>a proceeding for the committal of a person for trial or sentence for an offence; and</TEXT>
        </PARAGRAPH>
        <PARAGRAPH>
            <TEXT>a proceeding relating to bail&#160;&#150;</TEXT>
        </PARAGRAPH>
        <TEXT>but does not include a prosecution that is a prescribed taxation offence within the meaning of Part III of the Taxation Administration Act 1953 of the Commonwealth;</TEXT>
   </DEFINITION>
```

This is my `XSL`:

```
<xsl:template name="DEFINITION" match="DEFINITION">
        
            <xsl:element name="body">
                <xsl:attribute name="break">before</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="defn">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id" />
                    <xsl:attribute name="scope" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="DEFINEDTERM" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(TEXT[1],'&#x96;','--')" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::TEXT[1])]" />
        
    </xsl:template>
```

As per my `XSL`, I want to do something with the `DEFINEDTERM` element and the `TEXT` element that immediately follows it.

Then I want to `apply-templates` to the rest of the elements, except for the `DEFINEDTERM` and `TEXT` element that have already been dealt with. Most importantly, I don't want to apply templates to the first `TEXT` element.

How do I achieve this, because my `XSL` above does not work.

I have other templates for `TEXT` and `PARAGRAPH`, but not `DEFINEDTERM`.  I have `<xsl:template match="*|@*" />` at the top of the `XSL`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the expected result nor a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I can  only guess you want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="DEFINITION">
    <body break="before">
        <defn id="" scope="">
            <xsl:value-of select="DEFINEDTERM" />
        </defn>
        <text>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(DEFINEDTERM/following-sibling::TEXT[1],'&#150;','--')" />
        </text>
    </body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (DEFINEDTERM  | DEFINEDTERM/following-sibling::TEXT[1])" />
</xsl:template>
```

At least that's what I understand as:

> I want to do something with the `DEFINEDTERM` element and the `TEXT` element that immediately follows it.

This is assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 or higher (otherwise you would not be able to use the `replace()` function).

--
P.S. You might want to make this a bit more efficient by defining `DEFINEDTERM/following-sibling::TEXT[1]` as a variable first, then referring to the variable instead.

Comment: I know that I am utilising a XLST 2.0 function, but just out of curiosity, what would be the second `select` in XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: Do you mean the third `select` that makes use of the  `except` operator?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the third select.

Comment: Since there is no `except` operator, you would need to use some awkward workaround, for example `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::DEFINEDTERM or generate-id()=generate-id(current()/DEFINEDTERM/following-sibling::TEXT[1]))]" />`.

Comment: Why doesn't this work:  `*[not(self::DEFINEDTERM/following-sibling::TEXT[1])]` ?

Comment: Because it selects all elements except `DEFINEDTERM`that has at least one following sibling named `TEXT`.